# Jobs layout stepping out of bounds in overall design

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The overall look and feel of all tabs on SO looks great, the questions, tags, users, badges all line up such that the content doesn't go after both the stack overflow image and the **ask question** button.

Hardly a good way to measure it but here's SO Q&A questions link:

[image]

Now here's the jobs selection link:

[image]

Notice the content going "out of bounds" it seems that this should be pretty consistent with the rest of the tabs.  There is a subtle change as you click on the links on the top right to see these in action.

Jobs doesn't really stick to the defined rules of the div or container have you.  You can easily tell by looking at the **post a job** link as well as how the content goes out of what would appear to be it's container.

In other words the ref blows the whistle here, out of bounds!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just pushed a fix. Everything should be updated now. Thank you.